# What Can I Do If My Test User Cannot Find My Open Testing App Version?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

After my app of the open testing version is released, many users feedback that they cannot find the app on HUAWEI AppGallery.
I have checked that they have accept the invitation. And the test is still within the validity period, too. So I can not figure the reason. Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the **Version information** page in AppGallery Connect, click **View details** to check whether the user has accepted your invitation. Only users who have accepted the invitation can find the app. If the status of a user is **Unsent** or **Invited**, you can send an invitation to the user again.

[image]

2. Make sure that your test is still within the validity period. Otherwise, your app will be removed from sale.
   [image]
3. Then, make sure you have selected the right data storage location. For example, if you want to invite users in **Germany**, select the Germany site. If you don't know the exact site where the test user resides, or you want to invite users from all over the world, select **All**. You are advised to select **All**. If you select the wrong storage location, you have to recreate the user list and release your open testing app version again.
   [image]
4. Finally, make sure the user in question has signed in to AppGallery using the account you invited, and that their location is included in your app release countries or regions. A user can find your app only when all preceding conditions are met.
   [image]
5. Suggest that the user use a GMS-based or HMS-based device to search for your app in case that your app may be filtered out for other devices.

   For more details, please check:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-betatest-introduction?ha_source=hms1

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. In my case country in the settings was the reason and I have not found this info in other places